# Can't enable wireless connections on Kali Linux virtual machine

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, kali-linux

I recently set up a Kali Linux machine on my laptop with the intention of being able to use the laptops wifi card in order to see all the available networks on the vm, but so far I haven't been able to do so.

I'm using VirtualBox. I ran `apt-get upgrade` and installed guest additions.

I went to the machine config on VirtualBox and on the network tab I established the network to Bridged Adapter and selected the laptops interface. Then I set the promiscuous mode to allow all, and checked the cable connected option (I also tried unchecking that option since I'm not using a cable but it still didn't work).

I can `ping 8.8.8.8` and `ifconfig` shows no interface. If you need more information feel free to ask for it and I'll provide it.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Any virtual machine on most any Virtual Machine app uses the Host network for network and Internet.

If you wish to use a card of your own, (a) use a USB wireless card, (b) make sure your VM has drivers for the wireless card you choose, and (c) enable USB pass through to the guest.  Restart the VM are making the pass through changes.

Once all set up and restarted, try setting up the card.